# React native navigation keep tab bar visible when showing modal

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to keep the tab bar visible when presenting a screen in modal mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not quite modal mode, this is actually possible by using `containedModal` instead of `modal`.

```js
const TabsStack = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TabsStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <TabsStack.Navigator>
      <TabsStack.Screen name="MyTabStack" component={MyTabNavigator} />
    </TabsStack.Navigator>
  );
};

const MyTab = createNativeStackNavigator();
const MyTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <MyTab.Navigator>
      <MyTab.Screen name="Info" component={InfoScreen} />
      <MyTab.Screen
        name="MyModal"
        component={MyModalScreen}
        // this line 
        options={{ presentation: "containedModal" }}
      />
    </MyTab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not sadly. I suggest using a Stack Navigator if you want to keep your screen visible. And then navigating between screens according to how you want your modal to behave.